How to delete orphaned Campaign Members
I have a Web-to-Lead form which adds Leads to a Campaign.
I had a lot of problems with hackers entering nonsense data through the form so I implemented a Flow which aimed to catch these and delete the Leads.
Unfortunately I didn't think about the CampaignMember objects, so now I have a Campaign with a load of CampaignMembers for which the Lead has been deleted.
I can't seem to get rid of them as I get the error 'Entity is deleted' if I try to delete them through the UI or via SOQL.
Can anyone advise how I get rid of these entries as they are filling up the CampaignMember list making it hard to process the valid entries we are getting.
Thanks




Can you possibly add some screenshots of the Campaign Member record showing the lookup to the Campaign as well as the empty field to the Lead? A screenshot of the error will also be helpful.
It might be useful to determine what "Entity" the error message is referring to?

Hi @AdriaanVanNiekerk - I have added some screenshots which I hope helps show the problem

Examine SELECT Id, LeadOrContactId FROM CampaignMember for some affected campaignMembers. If there is a value in that field but the corresponding lead or contact is truly deleted, then I'd resort to using apex to delete the CampaignMember(s) with invalid references.  You could also restore the deleted leads/contacts from Recylce Bin, then delete CMs first, then leads/contacts but that really shouldn't be necessary. You might also try UX deleting in Classic though I doubt that will help

Hi @cropredy - I had a look with Classic and the CampaignMembers do not show there. I have tried various attempts to delete them using Apex and that also fails with the ENTITY_IS_DELETED error. I also tried to delete them using Database.delete(cmToDelete, false) which I have seen others suggest might work, but it does not. Any other ideas?

wait, what?  In Classic the Campaign Members don't appear but they do in Lightning?  That implies the CMs are in fact deleted but Lightning is showing them in their soft-deleted state. What is the value of the IsDeleted field?

IsDeleted = false for all records

@cropredy I thought you would be interested to know that I raised a ticket with Salesforce for this and they have now finally deleted these entries for me. I am hoping they will also provide an explanation as to why it happened - it sounds like they have had the problem before.

please add an answer to your question with the results of the support call; then after 48 hours, you can accept your own answer. This will benefit the community

Usually when I get the "Entity is deleted" error, is when I have deleted the selected record already, but the list (in Dev Console, or related list) haven't been refreshed.
From the related list:

Refresh the webpage,
select one CampaignMember record and delete it.
Refresh the related list and see if it is still there.

Similarly with Dev Console:

refresh the webpage,
select one record,
copy its record Id,
delete it,
verify it is gone by querying its record Id, or refreshing Dev Console

Once you can do the above without any errors, then you can select more than one record and delete them in one go. Just make sure to wait a minute or two (in Dev Console especially) and refresh if necessary to see the list shrinking...
Good luck!

No, that is not what happening.....no matter how you try to delete the entries, they never disappear
